# getResultList() performance is slow

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get a list from my database, the query performance is fast(0.04sec) from DB side, but when i'm trying to use it in application it's taking time(8 sec) to load the list.

I have already tried CreateNativeQuery instead of createNamedQuery but i haven't seen any improvement.

```
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("findMostUsedPlaylists");
q.setMaxResults(20);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final List<Playlist> results = (List<Playlist>) q.getResultList();


@NamedQuery( name = "findMostUsedPlaylists", query = "select p from Playlist p where p.sharing = 'PUBLIC' order by p.useCount desc")
```

Comment: Enable SQL logging, and post all the SQL queries that are executed when executing this code. Post the code of Playlist

Comment: it should be select p.name   . is it ? may be typo

Comment: You have plenty of associations eagerly loaded, so... Hibernate eagerly loads them. And since they seem to be recursive, this only makes things worse. You need to understand what you force Hibernate to do when you mark an association as eager.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Loading plenty of associations eagerly in my Playlist class is the problem.

```
List<Playlist> results = new ArrayList<>();

final List<Object> sqlOutput = em.createNativeQuery("select * from playlist p where 
p.sharing = 'PUBLIC' order by p.use_count desc").setMaxResults(20).getResultList();

// i'm just showing an example here.
for (Object o : sqlOutput) {
    Object[] row = (Object[])o;
    Playlist l = new Playlist();
    l.setPlaylistId( ((BigInteger) row[0]).longValue());
    l.setHidden((Boolean) row[1]);
    results.add(l);
}
return results;
```

This resolved the problem. I can see the results load much faster than they used to be.